# How to echo specific value from database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

Here's the layout of my table (`content`):

```
id, shortcode, message
1, blinds01, Random Message
2, shutters88, Random Message
3, windows12, Random Message
```

Here's the PHP I'm using to get all of the rows:

```
<?php
$host = "removed";
$user = "removed";
$pass = "removed";
$database = "removed";

$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $database);

$query = "SELECT * FROM `content`";

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

What I'm having issues with is not understanding how to echo data.

For example, what PHP code what I use to echo the `message` column where `id = 2`?

I know that I could just update my query to get that specific information, but I need to get a lot of different `message` fields on the same page and don't want to be querying the database 100 times per page load (which is why I'm querying all rows in the table).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to fetch the results and loop through them.

Comment: Please show your query first. Also, how exactly do you plan on showing the data on your page? You need to explain it clearly by providing a screenshot or something.

Comment: Come on. There must be dozens of tutorials that show how to retrieve and display information from a database using PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP documentation gives a good example similar to what you want to do: http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.examples-basic.php. In your case, it would be something like:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $database);

$query = "SELECT * FROM `content`";

$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    if ($row["id"] == 2) {
        echo $row["message"];
    }

$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: If you have 10 million records, you'll loop through all of them with this query.

Comment: Yup, he wanted the whole recordset to loop through

Answer (score 0):

This is a example from [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp) and for "MyGuests" table and his columns you need a code like this (How a person mentioned above, you need to fetch then result and loop through them):

```
`$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 } 

 $sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
 $result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row THIS IS WHERE YOU PRINT EACH ROW FROM THE QUERY 
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " .        $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
  }
 } else {
 echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();`
```

You only have to use your own table, columns, variables, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to fetch message where id= 1

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT message FROM content WHERE id='1' LIMIT 1");
    $data = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

    echo $data["message"];
```